# Usage of "as" in a context

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? The part that I am not confident about is the usage of "as". Can you please see the use of "as" in the parenthesis within the following sentence? Also if the following sentence doesn't sound smooth enough, can you please advise me why?

> Up to this point, the item is described (as) it has full warranty until 10/2013 but this is not true.

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify. What is the relevance of your sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> *Up to this point, the item is described (as) it has full warranty until 10/2013 but this is not true.

I'm afraid this is not correct. What you could say instead:

> Up to this point, the item is described **as having** full warranty until 10/2013, but this is not true.
>
> Up to this point, the item is described **as if it had** full warranty until 10/2013, but this is not true.

If you use *describe as*, you need to either continue with an adjective or participle *(described as yellow / described as being too large)*, or with a hypothetical *if* clause *(it is described as if it were blue)*, or with a noun *(described as a large box with holes)*. The hypothetical *if* clause seems a bit wordy here, and I'd prefer some other verb that *have*:

> Up to this point, the item is described **as coming with a** full warranty until 10/2013, but this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The function of "as" in the example is to show the supposed equivalence between the description of the item, and the properties of the item itself. As the properties which the item is said to have had at various points in the past were to have applied to it immediately at those times, the phrase "it has" should be replaced with the present (rather than past) participle of "have". "Up to" could do with being replaced with "up until", as the limit which you are describing is a point in time, rather than a numerical quantity. As you are talking about past events which have been completed, I would change "the item is described" to "the item has been described". A warranty is a legal document; an item, rather than merely a property which an object can have, and so you should change "having full warranty" to "having a full warranty" or "having full warranty cover", in order for it to be grammatically correct. I would also tend to soften the "not true" part of the last sentence to "not the case", as its slightly decreased directness might afford it more dignity in a business context, without losing any of the force of what you're attempting to convey. Lastly, I would add a comma to separate the second and last parts of the sentence, in order to make it more readable. This gives:

"Up until this point, the item has been described as having full warranty cover until 10/2013, but this is not the case."

Answer (score -1):

"Currently" and "presently" are similar but don't imply anything about the past.

"Historically" is similar but doesn't imply anything about the present.

"To date", "so far", "as yet", "thus far", "until now", "up to now"... all should work fine in this context, as does the original "up to this point".

"hitherto" is possibly the closest you can find in a single word, though it's used a little differently.

Note another grammar issue in "as it have" - should probably be "as if it has" or probably better, "as having". I would probably phrase this as:

"To date, the item has been described as having a full warranty until 10/2013, but this has never been the case."

Comment: This is my first time to use this site and never expected your answer would be offered this fast. I truly appreciate your help on this question although I acknowledge my question was unclear.